# Why is there all this black space between each of the images?

Tags: android, xml

When I run this XML in an android app, it shows perfectly in the emulator. But when ran in the actual device, there are huge blank spaces between each of the images. I'm trying to create a simple social media type app.

Also, I am wondering how I can take user input, such as a new post they create, and upload it into the feed of the app.

```
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="0dp"
        android:minHeight="50dp">

        <Button
            android:onClick="viewBanditos"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Banditos"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:layout_gravity="top|fill"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="#DFCF00"
            android:background="#272727"/>

        <Button
            android:onClick="newPostPage"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="New Post"
            android:layout_weight="1.0"
            android:textColor="#DFCF00"
            android:background="#272727"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Leave The City"
            android:textColor="#DFCF00"
            android:background="#272727"
            android:onClick="leaveTheCity"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:background="#0E0E0E"
            android:gravity="top">

            <EditText
                android:background="#272727"
                android:ems="10"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:inputType="textPassword"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:hint="Whats on your mind?"
                android:typeface="monospace"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:textColor="#DFCF00"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="top">

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/meme1"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:padding="10dp"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:gravity="top">

                    <ImageView
                        android:src="@drawable/meme2"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="top"/>

                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

        </LinearLayout>

    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can you give an example of how your layout should look like

Comment: Okay. I am going for a look that would be akin to an Instagram style feed. A picture/video, and underneath a like button, a share button, and a comment button. The problem I'm having is when I run what u have so far on the actual phone, what I see is the image and all the buttons, but there is a huge amount of black space between each image and buttons.